# Tomcat JNDI Resource - Class not found: oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, jndi

**The Problem**

Anytime I start my Tomcat server via Eclipse I always get a **Class not found** error:

```
SEVERE: Exception processing Global JNDI Resources
javax.naming.NamingException: Class not found: oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource
    at org.apache.naming.factory.BeanFactory.getObjectInstance(BeanFactory.java:136)
```

**The Setup**

My **server.xml** file has a resource setup like:

```
<GlobalNamingResources>
    <Resource name="sub1" auth="Container"
              type="oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource"
              factory="org.apache.naming.factory.BeanFactory"
              user="****" password="*****"
              URL="**************************************" />
</GlobalNamingResources>
```

**context.xml** has an entry that looks like so:

```
<ResourceLink name="dataSource/sub1" global="sub1" type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
```

On my application, I'm using Oracle's JDBC driver - **classes12.jar**

**The Question**

What do I need to fix on the Tomcat server so that it can find the appropriate class - `oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource`.  My first guess would be that **classes12.jar** needs to be copied to a folder somewhere on the server.  I'm not even totally sure where the folder on Windows for Eclipse...  any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming Tomcat 6, the required library needs to be copied to `$CATALINA_HOME\lib`.

From the [Tomcat documentation on setting up JDBC DataSources](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html#JDBC_Data_Sources):

> **1. Install Your JDBC Driver**
>
> Use of the JDBC Data Sources JNDI
>   Resource Factory requires that you
>   make an appropriate JDBC driver
>   available to both Tomcat internal
>   classes and to your web application.
>   This is most easily accomplished by
>   installing the driver's JAR file(s)
>   into the $CATALINA_HOME/lib directory,
>   which makes the driver available both
>   to the resource factory and to your
>   application.

Also, I would avoid using `classes12.zip`. It is meant to be used in Java 1.2 and 1.3 runtime environments only. Use `ojdbc14.jar` if you are stuck with Java 1.4. Or use the recommended `ojdbc6.jar`/`ojdbc5.jar` for the Java 6 or Java 5 environments.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest fix, assuming that `OracleXADataSource` is a class in `classes12.jar`, is to copy that JAR into [Tomcat's lib directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267953/managing-libraries-in-tomcat).

- Tomcat 5: `$CATALINA_HOME/common/lib`
- Tomcat 6: `$CATALINA_HOME/lib`

Comment: That sounds like a good fix to me.  I'm trying to hunt down where Tomcat's root directory is with MyEclipse 8.x

Answer (score 1):

Not classes12.jar; that's JDK 1.2 vintage.  Your Oracle JDBC driver JAR ought to match your JDK and Oracle versions (e.g. ojdbc16.jar for JDK 1.6).

Put that in your Tomcat /server/lib for Tomcat version 5.x and /lib for Tomcat version 6.x and higher.

I'd also recommend not altering your server.xml file.  Better to put that information in your project's META-INF/context.xml file.

Comment: +2 if I could do that... your additional tips were very helpful.

Comment: I no longer needed the answer to my above question anymore now that I don't need to depend on the server.  Thanks again... I feel liberated.

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html#Oracle_8i,_9i_&_10g):

> Drivers for older Oracle versions may
>   be distributed as *.zip files rather
>   than *.jar files. Tomcat will only use
>   *.jar files installed in $CATALINA_HOME/lib

So yes, you have to put the jar in $CATALINA_HOME/lib

Answer (score 0):

Copy the classes12.jar in tomcat's  /common/lib directory .