# Tomcat hot deployment, JDBC driver failed to unregister

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc

I have the exception after updating a file and hot deployment it to `Tomcat` server.
Does anybody know what is wrong?

```
SEVERE: The web application [/app] registered the JDBC driver [org.postgresql.Driver]  
but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped.
To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
```

Env.

```
     - Tomcat 6 or 7 (the same error)
     - Eclipse Helios
     - JDK 1.7.0_55 with "Default VM parameters":
       -Xms256M -Xmx512M -XX:PermSize=256M -XX:MaxPermSize=512M
```

Comment: Probably repeated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320400/to-prevent-a-memory-leak-the-jdbc-driver-has-been-forcibly-unregistered

Comment: Read this it gave you proper idea regarding this problem.
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320400/to-prevent-a-memory-leak-the-jdbc-driver-has-been-forcibly-unregistered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320400/to-prevent-a-memory-leak-the-jdbc-driver-has-been-forcibly-unregistered)

Answer (score 1):

Meaning of message is that Tomcat already took an action to correct leak caused by not unregistering JDBC driver.

If you're unsure how to unregister JDBC driver in ServletContextListener, you can try something like this:

```
Enumeration<java .sql.Driver> drivers = java.sql.DriverManager.getDrivers();
while (drivers.hasMoreElements()) {
    java.sql.Driver driver = drivers.nextElement();
    try {
       java.sql.DriverManager.deregisterDriver(driver);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //log exception or ignore
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the correct JDBC Driver jar and download to the WEB-INF lib folder.

Comment: You shouldn't deploy the JDBC driver with the application. See
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320400/to-prevent-a-memory-leak-the-jdbc-driver-has-been-forcibly-unregistered

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19189312/jdbc-driver-has-been-forcibly-unregistered-by-tomcat-7-why

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24850091/the-web-application-registered-the-jdbc-driver-com-mysql-jdbc-driver-but-fa