# The web application [] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-security

I've seen few similar issues on stackoverflow but i could not figure out how i can solve my problem. After adding Spring Security to my Spring MVC project i got following exception:

```
Jul 20, 2014 3:18:04 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
SEVERE: The web application [] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
```

Here is my mysql-connecter in the **pom.xml**

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.31</version>
    </dependency>
```

Here are classes that i've added:

```
@Component
@Transactional
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService{

@Autowired
private UserDAO userDAO;

@Autowired
private UserAssembler userAssembler;

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserDetailsServiceImpl.class);

@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException {
    User user = userDAO.findByEmail(username);

    if(null == user) throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found");

    return userAssembler.buildUserFromUser(user);
}
}
```

and assembler

```
 @Service("assembler")

public class UserAssembler {

@Autowired
private UserDAO userDAO;

@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public User buildUserFromUser(net.viralpatel.contact.model.User user) {
    String role = "ROLE_USER";//userEntityDAO.getRoleFromUserEntity(userEntity);

    Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
    authorities.add(new GrantedAuthorityImpl(role));

    return new User(user.getLogin(), user.getPassword(), true, true, true, true,  authorities);
}
}
```

Here is my spring-security.xml

```
<beans:bean id="webexpressionHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler" />

<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/account/*" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/account/overview" authentication-failure-url="/login?error=true"/>
    <remember-me/>
</http>

<beans:bean id="myUserDetailsService" class="net.viralpatel.contact.service.UserDetailsServiceImpl" />


<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="myUserDetailsService" />
</authentication-manager>
```

**EDITED:**

```
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /opt/idea-IU-135.909/bin::/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
Jul 20, 2014 3:58:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener lifecycleEvent
SEVERE: Failed to load class com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver during Tomcat start to prevent possible memory leaks.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320400/to-prevent-a-memory-leak-the-jdbc-driver-has-been-forcibly-unregistered)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I did was just to put the `mysql-connector-java-5.1.31-bin.jar` in `$CATALINA_HOME/lib`. No modifications to `server.xml`.

Comment: You're right @titi-wangsa-bin-damhore. But there is another root of memory leak regarding MySQL's JDBC driver: _Abandonded connection cleanup thread_. Updated my answer to reflect.

Answer (score 22):

Your application doesn't have a flaw. It is the design of JDBC. The JDBC driver gets loaded and registered by the webapp when it creates a database connection for the first time.

That means that the driver is loaded with the web application class loader. On undeployment the driver doesn't get deregistered which in turn prevents your webapp classes from GC. That creates effectively a memory leak.

To prevent this particular memory leak you should edit your `tomcat/conf/server.xml` and change

```
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
```

to

```
<Listener 
className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener"
classesToInitialize="com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver" />
```

- *With mysql-connector-java-8.0.x use `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver` instead*

Exclude the JDBC driver from your webapp artifact and put it into the `tomcat/lib` directory.
Now the JDBC driver gets loaded by Tomcat on startup and isn't linked to any webapps class loader.

**Why should I modify the server.xml?**

Another memory leaks manifests due to MySQL's 'Abandoned connection cleanup thread'. This thread starts with the first request and holds a reference to the webapp's classloader. With `classesToInitialize` you can prevent this memory leak too.

References:

- [org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/listeners.html#JRE_Memory_Leak_Prevention_Listener_-_org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener) tomcat-doc v7.0
- [AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/connector-j/5.1/en/news-5-1-41.html) notes in v5.1.41
- [com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-j/blob/release/5.1/src/com/mysql/jdbc/NonRegisteringDriver.java) source v5.1
- [com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-j/blob/release/8.0/src/main/user-impl/java/com/mysql/cj/jdbc/NonRegisteringDriver.java) source v8.0
- [mysql-connector-java](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-api-changes.html) changes in v8.0

Comment: unfortunately i got new error, please take a look at my edited question above

Comment: by the way i tried to put mysql-connector-java-5.1.31-bin.jar into my /tomcat/lib folder, but it didn't help me

Comment: sorry. forgot to mention that driver should be put into tomcat/lib. updated  my answer. ClassNotFoundException is weird! I checked mysql-connector-java-5.1.31-bin.jar for NonRegisteringDriver. Class exists in jar!

Comment: Is there a solution with glassfish ?