# Spring Boot Rest Api's response too slow on production environement

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, amazon-ec2

My spring boot application becomes slow after 1-2 days when I deploy it on production server. I'm using AWS EC2 instance. In start the speed is fine, but after a couple of days I have to restart my instance to get back the desired performance. Any hint what might be wrong here?

Comment: A lot of things.

Comment: Like what? Any example please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so after some analysis (Thread dumping of my tomcat server on production) I found out that there were some processes (code-smells) which were taking all of my CPU space, and hence my instance was becoming slow, and effecting the performance of my application overall.

Answer (score 1):

Have you check for memory leakage in application as it is nothing to do with EC2 instance. As you mention it was working fine after restart.

It is not best practice to use embed server on production.

I would suggest you should use AWS Elastic Beanstalk service for deploying spring boot application, there is no additional charge on it.

Comment: Can you recommend some ways of checking & resolving memory leaks?

Comment: `It is not best practice to use embed server on production` can you explain why?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39626267/spring-boot-embedded-container-or-war-file-in-an-external-container-for-producti