# Unable to open application after docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

After composing docker file, everything builds fine but after doing `docker ps`
it shows no containers are running.

Below is my `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'
services:
  web-app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: web-app/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    links:
      - app-db

  app-db:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: app-db/Dockerfile

    environment:
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
    - MYSQL_DATABASE=Optimize
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
```

and `Dockerfile` for web-app is like

```
FROM aallam/oracle-java
    
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
ENV TOMCAT_MAJOR_VERSION=8
ENV TOMCAT_VERSION=8.5.14
ENV TOMCAT_HOME=/opt/tomcat

RUN apt-get update && \
  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

WORKDIR /tmp

RUN groupadd tomcat && \
    useradd -s /bin/false -g tomcat -d $TOMCAT_HOME tomcat && \
    mkdir $TOMCAT_HOME && \
    #wget http://mirrors.standaloneinstaller.com/apache/tomcat/tomcat-$TOMCAT_MAJOR_VERSION/v$TOMCAT_VERSION/bin/apache-tomcat-$TOMCAT_VERSION.tar.gz && \
    wget http://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-8/v8.0.23/bin/apache-tomcat-8.0.23.tar.gz && \
    tar xzvf apache-tomcat-8*tar.gz -C $TOMCAT_HOME --strip-components=1 && \
    chown -R tomcat:tomcat $TOMCAT_HOME && \
    chmod -R g+r $TOMCAT_HOME/conf && \
    chmod g+x $TOMCAT_HOME/conf && \
    rm -rf apache-tomcat-$TOMCAT_VERSION.tar.gz

WORKDIR /

ADD /web-app/tomcat-run.sh /tomcat-run.sh
ADD /web-app/run.sh /run.sh
ADD /web-app/supervisord-tomcat.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord-tomcat.conf
ADD /web-app/settings.xml $TOMCAT_HOME/conf/settings.xml
ADD /web-app/tomcat-users.xml $TOMCAT_HOME/conf/tomcat-users.xml
ADD /web-app/context.xml $TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/manager/META-INF/context.xml
RUN chmod 755 /*.sh

COPY /web-app/target/*.war $TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/

expose 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["/run.sh"]
```

and the `Dockerfile` for database for is like

```
FROM aallam/oracle-java
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
RUN apt-get update && \
  apt-get -yq install mysql-server supervisor && \
  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

#WORKDIR /
ADD /app-db/bind_0.cnf /etc/mysql/conf.d/bind_0.cnf
ADD /app-db/mysql-run.sh /mysql-run.sh
ADD /app-db/supervisord-mysql.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord-mysql.conf

VOLUME ["/var/lib/mysql"]
expose 3306
```

after `docker-compose up -d` this was the output in the terminal

> user@ubuntu:~/Creating optdocker_app-db_1
>
> user@ubuntu:~/Creating optdocker_web-app_1

adding `docker-compose logs` and `netstat -tln`

```
user@ubuntu:~/Opt-Docker$ netstat -tln
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:32000         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10000           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::40645                :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:9000          :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:9001          :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::10000                :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:36241         :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::42801                :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::37971                :::*                    LISTEN     
user@ubuntu:~/Opt-Docker$ docker-compose logs
Attaching to optdocker_web-app_1, optdocker_app-db_1
user@ubuntu:~/Opt-Docker$
```

but `docker ps` doesn't give anything. can anyone tell where and what i am doing wrong

`docker ps -a` output

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS               NAMES
3a93140ab6f4        optdocker_web-app   "/bin/bash"         16 minutes ago      Exited (0) 16 minutes ago                       optdocker_web-app_1
53b7ec265fac        optdocker_app-db    "/bin/bash"         16 minutes ago      Exited (0) 16 minutes ago                       optdocker_app-db_1
```

Comment: Can you add some log or output?

Comment: And be sure that port 3306 is not used by any application.

Comment: You mean `docker-compose logs` ?

Comment: Yes, also if any application logs please

Comment: What does `run.sh` do? Can you provide the contents of the script?

Comment: `#!/bin/bash

exec supervisord -n`

Comment: What is the output of `docker ps -a`?

Comment: @kstromeiraos provided in question

Comment: looks like your entrypoint is wrong. have you tried to run them standalone and watch what the console output is? if it gives you exited by 0, your entrypoint stoped because the task finished and the container stops working.

Comment: @Gabbax0r yup.... entry point is not working after running the `Dockerfile` of web app. Can you please help me with this

Comment: try just ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash"]. if its run you can skript  the programm start on your own

Comment: Can you add  docker logs of both of the containers?

Comment: Just by changing `ENTRYPOINT` it worked. Thanks @Gabbax0r

Answer (score 0):

Update *Dockerfile* in *web-app* like this:

```
FROM aallam/oracle-java

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
ENV TOMCAT_MAJOR_VERSION=8
ENV TOMCAT_VERSION=8.5.14
ENV TOMCAT_HOME=/opt/tomcat

RUN apt-get update && \
apt-get -yq install supervisor && \
  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

WORKDIR /tmp

RUN groupadd tomcat && \
    useradd -s /bin/false -g tomcat -d $TOMCAT_HOME tomcat && \
    mkdir $TOMCAT_HOME && \
    #wget http://mirrors.standaloneinstaller.com/apache/tomcat/tomcat-$TOMCAT_MAJOR_VERSION/v$TOMCAT_VERSION/bin/apache-tomcat-$TOMCAT_VERSION.tar.gz && \
    wget http://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-8/v8.0.23/bin/apache-tomcat-8.0.23.tar.gz && \
    tar xzvf apache-tomcat-8*tar.gz -C $TOMCAT_HOME --strip-components=1 && \
    chown -R tomcat:tomcat $TOMCAT_HOME && \
    chmod -R g+r $TOMCAT_HOME/conf && \
    chmod g+x $TOMCAT_HOME/conf && \
    rm -rf apache-tomcat-$TOMCAT_VERSION.tar.gz

WORKDIR /

ADD /web-app/tomcat-run.sh /tomcat-run.sh
ADD /web-app/run.sh /run.sh
ADD /web-app/supervisord-tomcat.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord-tomcat.conf
ADD /web-app/settings.xml $TOMCAT_HOME/conf/settings.xml
ADD /web-app/tomcat-users.xml $TOMCAT_HOME/conf/tomcat-users.xml
ADD /web-app/context.xml $TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/manager/META-INF/context.xml
RUN chmod 755 /*.sh

COPY /web-app/target/*.war $TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/

expose 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["/run.sh"]
```

Duplicate run.sh for both *web-app* and *app-db* folder.

Update *Dockerfile* in *app-db* like this:

```
FROM aallam/oracle-java
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
RUN apt-get update && \
  apt-get -yq install mysql-server supervisor && \
  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

#WORKDIR /
ADD /app-db/run.sh /run.sh
ADD /app-db/bind_0.cnf /etc/mysql/conf.d/bind_0.cnf
ADD /app-db/mysql-run.sh /mysql-run.sh
ADD /app-db/supervisord-mysql.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord-mysql.conf

VOLUME ["/var/lib/mysql"]
expose 3306
ENTRYPOINT ["/run.sh"]
```

Then run commands:

```
docker-compose up
docker ps
```

Output will be like this and system is up:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED                  STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
a60682b914a4        test_web-app        "/run.sh"           Less than a second ago   Up 9 seconds        0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp   test_web-app_1
607522cac623        test_app-db         "/run.sh"           Less than a second ago   Up 9 seconds        0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp   test_app-db_1
```

To connect MySQL server in `app-db` container, your JDBC connection url in your project should be something like this:

```
"jdbc:mysql://DOCKER_MACHINE_IP:3306/DB_NAME".
```

At the *app-db* container side, access MySQL from command line, create and give permissions for user with DOCKER_MACHINE_IP:

```
> CREATE USER 'root'@'DOCKER_MACHINE_IP' IDENTIFIED BY 'root_password'; 
> GRANT ALL ON *.* to root@'DOCKER_MACHINE_IP' IDENTIFIED BY 'root_password';
> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: The containers are up but i guess its not connecting with the MySQL [here are the logs](https://gist.github.com/Beanben/eb28d3084b9caf899728842d8c8980b5) can anyone help me

Comment: It seems project under target folder can't start before connecting database. Can you add catalina and localhost full logs? Also please check whether mysql has  the database you want to create.

Comment: Yup there is no database which i wanted to create and also please find the [logs here](https://gist.github.com/Beanben/d0b81b87ef787409e613223318eb86ac)

Comment: Deploying process look like healthy. SEVERE logs are related with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24850091 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320400.

Comment: I edit  the answer for accessing MySQL from application.

Comment: after implementing your solution getting this error `ERROR: for app-db  Cannot start service app-db: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec: \"/run.sh\": permission denied"`

Comment: did you give permissions from MySQL?