# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.mysql.cj.protocol.ExportControlled

Tags: java, mysql, spring

Full stack trace:

```
[2021-04-29T20:35:39.155+0200] [glassfish 5.0] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.web.util] [tid: _ThreadID=29 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1619721328851] [timeMillis: 1619721339155] [levelValue: 900] [[
      The web application [unknown] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.]]
    
    [2021-04-29T20:35:55.926+0200] [glassfish 5.0] [WARNING] [] [com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool] [tid: _ThreadID=29 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1619721328851] [timeMillis: 1619721355926] [levelValue: 900] [[
      Bad pool size config, start 3 < min 5. Using 5 as start.]]
    
    [2021-04-29T20:36:01.282+0200] [glassfish 5.0] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.web.util] [tid: _ThreadID=56 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1619721361282] [levelValue: 900] [[
      The web application [/cv-project-1] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.]]
    
    [2021-04-29T20:36:01.379+0200] [glassfish 5.0] [SEVERE] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=121 _ThreadName=Thread-9] [timeMillis: 1619721361379] [levelValue: 1000] [[
      Exception in thread "Resource Destroyer in BasicResourcePool.close()" ]]
    
    [2021-04-29T20:36:01.382+0200] [glassfish 5.0] [SEVERE] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=121 _ThreadName=Thread-9] [timeMillis: 1619721361382] [levelValue: 1000] [[
      java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.mysql.cj.protocol.ExportControlled
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.NetworkResources.forceClose(NetworkResources.java:53)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.AbstractSocketConnection.forceClose(AbstractSocketConnection.java:103)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.quit(NativeProtocol.java:1235)
        at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.quit(NativeSession.java:174)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.realClose(ConnectionImpl.java:1738)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.close(ConnectionImpl.java:718)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection.close(NewPooledConnection.java:642)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection.closeMaybeCheckedOut(NewPooledConnection.java:255)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.destroyResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:622)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$1DestroyResourceTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1114)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.destroyResource(BasicResourcePool.java:1139)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.destroyResource(BasicResourcePool.java:1100)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$100(BasicResourcePool.java:44)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$5.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1354)
    ]]
    
    [2021-04-29T20:36:02.421+0200] [glassfish 5.0] [SEVERE] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=77 _ThreadName=Thread-9] [timeMillis: 1619721362421] [levelValue: 1000] [[
      Exception in thread "mysql-cj-abandoned-connection-cleanup" ]]
    
    [2021-04-29T20:36:02.422+0200] [glassfish 5.0] [SEVERE] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=77 _ThreadName=Thread-9] [timeMillis: 1619721362422] [levelValue: 1000] [[
      java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.mysql.cj.protocol.ExportControlled
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.NetworkResources.forceClose(NetworkResources.java:53)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread$ConnectionFinalizerPhantomReference.finalizeResources(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:248)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.finalizeResource(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:226)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.run(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:93)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    ]]
    
    [2021-04-29T20:36:21.066+0200] [glassfish 5.0] [WARNING] [] [com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool] [tid: _ThreadID=56 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1619721381066] [levelValue: 900] [[
      Bad pool size config, start 3 < min 5. Using 5 as start.]]
```

I dont know, this drive me crazy. This is just copy of previous project which worked fine and then just re-created new project and im getting this error. I have mysql connection in library

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The web application registered the JDBC driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24850091/the-web-application-registered-the-jdbc-driver-com-mysql-jdbc-driver-but-fa)

Comment: No, but I fixed it. How? I dont know.