# How can I prevent Tomcat6 from pre-loading JDBC Drivers in WEB-INF/lib?

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc

I have a number of JDBC Driver jar files in my webapp's WEB-INF/lib - e.g. oracle and SQL-Server. In Tomcat7, if the webapp only uses oracle, the SQL-Server driver doesn't get registered, but in Tomcat6 it does (I can see this from my contextDestroyed() in a ServletContextListener, which de-registers Drivers loaded by this classloader).

Is Tomcat6 somehow pre-loading classes from jars in WEB-INF/lib? If so, can this be disabled?

(I know these jars would be better in the shared lib, but this is another issue...)

Answer (score 1):

Never ever put drivers in the webapp class path. Put it always into the server's classpath.

Declare a `DataSource` then in your `context.xml` and then free the resources with [this](http://mo-tomcat-ext.sourceforge.net/user-guide.html#CloseableResourceListener).

Comment: It's not really answering the question, but I totally agree with your statement. +1

Comment: Yes, but as I said, this is a separate issue. I am stuck with having to have the drivers where they are, as different webapps may use different driver versions, etc. Just wondered about the pre-loading thing...

Comment: You cannot use different version of the same class file. This would probably require OSGi.

Comment: Yes you can, because they are in different ClassLoaders - each webapp has its own ClassLoader.

Comment: @Michael-O why are drivers in `WEB-INF/lib` an issue? I suspect it matters when the server creates the connection pool, but if the app manages it (via Spring, etc), `WEB-INF/lib` is where the libraries _should_ reside?

Comment: @raffian,the thing is that if you load the same driver twice you might get into `DriverManager` problems. It was not designed for multi-classloaders. It assumes that the driver is always loaded once per VM. Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7198049/696632) answer please.