# Driver not found for hibernate with Tapestry 5.4

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, tapestry

I'm trying to upgrade a project to Tapestry 5.4 because I want to use Bootstrap. Currently it uses tapestry-hibernate 5.3.7 with MySQL. Almost everything works. But when I try to use Hibernate, it says "No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/databaseName".

Now, this question has been asked before and the answer has been 'the driver isn't on the classpath' or 'you typed the url in wrong'. But I am absolutely, 100% positive that the driver is there. It's in the war file. Here is the entry in pom.xml:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.27</version>
        </dependency>
```

And I am absolutely 100% sure that I typed the url right because it worked with Tapestry 5.3.7.

I've also tried adding the driver manually. Also, I've tried other databases and it's given the same error. I pasted the stack trace below. Looking at the source for java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection, it appears that it's checking a list of drivers but that the list is empty.

```
    [ERROR] hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate HHH000299: Could not complete schema update
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/preparedMindDatabase
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:596)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:187)
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.prepare(SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:495)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1741)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1779)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.hibernate.HibernateSessionSourceImpl.<init>(HibernateSessionSourceImpl.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.ConstructorInvoker.invoke(ConstructorInvoker.java:49)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.LoggingInvokableWrapper.invoke(LoggingInvokableWrapper.java:42)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.invoke(OperationTrackerImpl.java:80)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.PerThreadOperationTracker.invoke(PerThreadOperationTracker.java:89)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryImpl.invoke(RegistryImpl.java:1112)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.ConstructionPlan.createObject(ConstructionPlan.java:60)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.ConstructorServiceCreator.createObject(ConstructorServiceCreator.java:61)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackingObjectCreator$1.invoke(OperationTrackingObjectCreator.java:45)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.invoke(OperationTrackerImpl.java:80)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.PerThreadOperationTracker.invoke(PerThreadOperationTracker.java:89)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryImpl.invoke(RegistryImpl.java:1112)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackingObjectCreator.createObject(OperationTrackingObjectCreator.java:49)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.SingletonServiceLifecycle.createService(SingletonServiceLifecycle.java:29)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.LifecycleWrappedServiceCreator.createObject(LifecycleWrappedServiceCreator.java:46)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.AdvisorStackBuilder.createObject(AdvisorStackBuilder.java:63)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.InterceptorStackBuilder.createObject(InterceptorStackBuilder.java:54)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RecursiveServiceCreationCheckWrapper.createObject(RecursiveServiceCreationCheckWrapper.java:60)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackingObjectCreator$1.invoke(OperationTrackingObjectCreator.java:45)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.invoke(OperationTrackerImpl.java:80)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.PerThreadOperationTracker.invoke(PerThreadOperationTracker.java:89)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryImpl.invoke(RegistryImpl.java:1112)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackingObjectCreator.createObject(OperationTrackingObjectCreator.java:49)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.services.JustInTimeObjectCreator.obtainObjectFromCreator(JustInTimeObjectCreator.java:66)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.services.JustInTimeObjectCreator.createObject(JustInTimeObjectCreator.java:54)
    at $HibernateSessionSource_61fa1b0ff12.delegate(Unknown Source)
    at $HibernateSessionSource_61fa1b0ff12.create(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.hibernate.HibernateSessionManagerImpl.<init>(HibernateSessionManagerImpl.java:31)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.hibernate.modules.HibernateCoreModule.buildHibernateSessionManager(HibernateCoreModule.java:94)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:51)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.LoggingInvokableWrapper.invoke(LoggingInvokableWrapper.java:42)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.invoke(OperationTrackerImpl.java:80)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.PerThreadOperationTracker.invoke(PerThreadOperationTracker.java:89)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryImpl.invoke(RegistryImpl.java:1112)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.ConstructionPlan.createObject(ConstructionPlan.java:60)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.ServiceBuilderMethodInvoker.createObject(ServiceBuilderMethodInvoker.java:60)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackingObjectCreator$1.invoke(OperationTrackingObjectCreator.java:45)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.invoke(OperationTrackerImpl.java:80)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.PerThreadOperationTracker.invoke(PerThreadOperationTracker.java:89)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryImpl.invoke(RegistryImpl.java:1112)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackingObjectCreator.createObject(OperationTrackingObjectCreator.java:49)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.services.PerThreadServiceCreator.createObject(PerThreadServiceCreator.java:47)
    at $HibernateSessionManager_61fa1b0ffd3.delegate(Unknown Source)
    at $HibernateSessionManager_61fa1b0ffd3.getSession(Unknown Source)
    at $HibernateSessionManager_61fa1b0ff4e.getSession(Unknown Source)
    at $Session_61fa1b0ffd2.readProperty(Unknown Source)
    at $Session_61fa1b0ffd2.createCriteria(Unknown Source)
    at $Session_61fa1b0fef9.createCriteria(Unknown Source)
    at com.salsaberries.preparedmind.pages.Register.advised$onSuccess_61fa1b0ffbf(Register.java:57)
    at com.salsaberries.preparedmind.pages.Register$Invocation_onSuccess_61fa1b0ffbe.proceedToAdvisedMethod(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.plastic.AbstractMethodInvocation.proceed(AbstractMethodInvocation.java:84)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.hibernate.CommitAfterWorker$1.advise(CommitAfterWorker.java:53)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.plastic.AbstractMethodInvocation.proceed(AbstractMethodInvocation.java:86)
    at com.salsaberries.preparedmind.pages.Register.onSuccess(Register.java)
    at com.salsaberries.preparedmind.pages.Register.dispatchComponentEvent(Register.java)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementImpl.dispatchEvent(ComponentPageElementImpl.java:942)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementImpl.processEventTriggering(ComponentPageElementImpl.java:1127)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementImpl.access$3100(ComponentPageElementImpl.java:62)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementImpl$5.invoke(ComponentPageElementImpl.java:1072)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementImpl$5.invoke(ComponentPageElementImpl.java:1069)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.invoke(OperationTrackerImpl.java:80)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.PerThreadOperationTracker.invoke(PerThreadOperationTracker.java:89)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryImpl.invoke(RegistryImpl.java:1112)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementResourcesImpl.invoke(ComponentPageElementResourcesImpl.java:145)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementImpl.triggerContextEvent(ComponentPageElementImpl.java:1068)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.InternalComponentResourcesImpl.triggerContextEvent(InternalComponentResourcesImpl.java:302)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.corelib.components.Form.onAction(Form.java:526)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.corelib.components.Form.dispatchComponentEvent(Form.java)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementImpl.dispatchEvent(ComponentPageElementImpl.java:942)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementImpl.processEventTriggering(ComponentPageElementImpl.java:1127)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementImpl.access$3100(ComponentPageElementImpl.java:62)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementImpl$5.invoke(ComponentPageElementImpl.java:1072)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementImpl$5.invoke(ComponentPageElementImpl.java:1069)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.invoke(OperationTrackerImpl.java:80)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.PerThreadOperationTracker.invoke(PerThreadOperationTracker.java:89)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryImpl.invoke(RegistryImpl.java:1112)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementResourcesImpl.invoke(ComponentPageElementResourcesImpl.java:145)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementImpl.triggerContextEvent(ComponentPageElementImpl.java:1068)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.ComponentEventRequestHandlerImpl.handle(ComponentEventRequestHandlerImpl.java:75)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.AjaxFilter.handle(AjaxFilter.java:42)
    at $ComponentEventRequestHandler_61fa1b0ffd1.handle(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.modules.TapestryModule$37.handle(TapestryModule.java:2202)
    at $ComponentEventRequestHandler_61fa1b0ffd1.handle(Unknown Source)
    at $ComponentEventRequestHandler_61fa1b0ff5c.handle(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.ComponentRequestHandlerTerminator.handleComponentEvent(ComponentRequestHandlerTerminator.java:43)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.services.InitializeActivePageName.handleComponentEvent(InitializeActivePageName.java:39)
    at $ComponentRequestHandler_61fa1b0ff5e.handleComponentEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.RequestOperationTracker$1.perform(RequestOperationTracker.java:55)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.RequestOperationTracker$1.perform(RequestOperationTracker.java:52)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.perform(OperationTrackerImpl.java:107)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.PerThreadOperationTracker.perform(PerThreadOperationTracker.java:100)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryImpl.perform(RegistryImpl.java:1117)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.RequestOperationTracker.handleComponentEvent(RequestOperationTracker.java:47)
    at $ComponentRequestHandler_61fa1b0ff5e.handleComponentEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.salsaberries.preparedmind.filters.HTTPHeaderFilter.handleComponentEvent(HTTPHeaderFilter.java:46)
    at $ComponentRequestFilter_61fa1b0ff5b.handleComponentEvent(Unknown Source)
    at $ComponentRequestHandler_61fa1b0ff5e.handleComponentEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.salsaberries.preparedmind.filters.SecurityFilter.handleComponentEvent(SecurityFilter.java:62)
    at $ComponentRequestFilter_61fa1b0ff5a.handleComponentEvent(Unknown Source)
    at $ComponentRequestHandler_61fa1b0ff5e.handleComponentEvent(Unknown Source)
    at $ComponentRequestHandler_61fa1b0ff23.handleComponentEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.ComponentEventDispatcher.dispatch(ComponentEventDispatcher.java:46)
    at $Dispatcher_61fa1b0ff26.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at $Dispatcher_61fa1b0ff20.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.modules.TapestryModule$RequestHandlerTerminator.service(TapestryModule.java:300)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.RequestErrorFilter.service(RequestErrorFilter.java:26)
    at $RequestHandler_61fa1b0ff21.service(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.modules.TapestryModule$3.service(TapestryModule.java:845)
    at $RequestHandler_61fa1b0ff21.service(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.modules.TapestryModule$2.service(TapestryModule.java:835)
    at $RequestHandler_61fa1b0ff21.service(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.StaticFilesFilter.service(StaticFilesFilter.java:89)
    at $RequestHandler_61fa1b0ff21.service(Unknown Source)
    at $RequestHandler_61fa1b0ff17.service(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.modules.TapestryModule$HttpServletRequestHandlerTerminator.service(TapestryModule.java:251)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.gzip.GZipFilter.service(GZipFilter.java:59)
    at $HttpServletRequestHandler_61fa1b0ff19.service(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.IgnoredPathsFilter.service(IgnoredPathsFilter.java:62)
    at $HttpServletRequestFilter_61fa1b0ff14.service(Unknown Source)
    at $HttpServletRequestHandler_61fa1b0ff19.service(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.modules.TapestryModule$1.service(TapestryModule.java:795)
    at $HttpServletRequestHandler_61fa1b0ff19.service(Unknown Source)
    at $HttpServletRequestHandler_61fa1b0ff13.service(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.TapestryFilter.doFilter(TapestryFilter.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Edit: And here is the hibernate configuration:

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
```

```
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/preparedMindDatabase</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">*******</property>
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.format_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</property>

</session-factory>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have a look at the method java.sql.DriverManager#getConnection where the exception is thrown, it seems that it's one of 2 possibilities:

1. the driver did not register itself. Modern drivers register themselves automatically when their class is loaded
2. The driver registered itself, but it's not visible by the classloader of the caller and so it get's skipped.

I would suggest to put some breakpoints on java.sql.DriverManager#getConnection and in java.sql.DriverManager#registerDriver to see what is going on.

What is strange is why was it working before. Usually we should put the driver in $TOMCAT_HOME/lib, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6981564/why-jdbc-driver-must-been-put-in-tomcat-home-lib-folder). There it is always visible to any part of the application and prevents registering drivers multiple times.

Try to remove the driver from the WAR and make sure it's in $TOMCAT_HOME/lib. If it doesn't work you can always edit the question with further findings, hope it helps.

Comment: The problem was that Tomcat was still loading the old driver, when I updated to the new driver it tried to load that too and that was causing some conflict. Putting the driver in $TOMCAT_HOME/lib as you suggested AND removing it from the WAR (and clearing the tomcat webapps folder) fixed the problem, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Where are the hibernate jars? Perhaps you've got some strange situation where hibernate is loaded by the bootstrap classloader but the driver is loaded by the war classloader.

Comment: That's interesting, it wasn't the case here but it could cause the same problem when upgrading.