# Suspected memory leak with Jdbc and Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc, memory-leaks

I am having theses messages in my tomcat logs :

***" org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
 A web application registered the JBDC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered."***

and

***"org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: A web application appears to have started a thread named [pool-820-thread-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak."***

Actually I have a JDBC driver (.jar) in my java project that I always deploy on a tomcat server as a .war (meaning the driver is always in the war/libs directory).

After my searches, I found a good starting of answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6981564/why-jdbc-driver-must-been-put-in-tomcat-home-lib-folder/7198049#7198049) but unfortunately I cannot comment yet on stackoverflow to have more details on the accepted answer.

Here are my questions :
 - Is the answer suggesting to remove completely the .jar from the war/libs directory ?
 - If yes, where do I put it? Because I do not get how to get rid completely of the .jar and still be able to make my tests locally to the database.

Please advice on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Tomcat 6.0 , there has been a feature to detect classloader memory leaks. Read more [here](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/MemoryLeakProtection). The above messages by tomcat are purely for information purpose and tomcat already took sufficient measures to avoid classloader leak by de-registering the `Driver`.

To prevent it as you have rightly pointed out , you can either move the jar completely to tomcat's lib folder where it wont be affected by a application context reload. Or you can explicitly call a `DriverManager.deregister(driver)`. (Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320400/to-prevent-a-memory-leak-the-jdbc-driver-has-been-forcibly-unregistered))

To understand more about ClassLoader leaks ([here](http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/rjc201))

To understand why its suggested to move it to `tomcat lib` from applications `WEB_INF/lib` you can read more [here.](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html)

**Edit in response to query in the comment**

No its not recommended to have multiple jars as it can lead to classcastexception. Each class is identified by combination of class name and classloader. Look at [this](http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/rebel-labs-tutorial-do-you-really-get-classloaders/4/) for a clearer understanding with an example.

The better approach according to me would be to write a servlet context listener and explicitly de-register your driver at context destroyed. This way you can keep you jdbc driver in your `web-inf/lib` and need not move it to `tomcat/lib`.

Even if you keep jars at multiple locations, according to the classloader hierarchy that tomcat follows which is different from what java delegation model (more info [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html)) , tomcat will pick up the jar in your `web-inf/lib` first.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Summet! Nevertheless, my remaining concern is to know how to handle my local development if I move my driver .jar into the server tomcat lib directory (since locally, I do not have tomcat for my debug purpose...). Or should I use the .jar as it is locally and then remove it from my .war before each deployment to the server?
Regards,

Comment: So, if I understand well, I can have a duplicate ?