# No suitable driver found for jdbc:db2 with db2jcc4.jar present in web-inf\lib

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc

I am trying to run a simple java web app that connects to a back end DB2 database(IBM dashdb) to get retrieve some data.

I am getting a weird error message when I try to run this application on a ubuntu hosted tomcat 8.5. 
I managed to get this application running on a tomcat v8 hosted on Windows.

The actual error message is:

> No suitable driver found for jdbc:db2://yp-dashdb......

I don't really understand why this is happening because I have the db2jcc4. in my web-inf\lib folder.
[image]

I thought it was something wrong with the library so I created a separate Java app to simply connect and retrieve some data from the database. That one works just fine with the same library.

This is the code used to set up the connection (I trimmed out some of the details).

```
private Connection conn = null;   
conn= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:db2://yp-dashdb...");
```

Keep in mind, that this exact same code works in a Standard Java app so the connection details work and there's no typo in the connection info.

Is there something obvious that I'm overlooking here?

Comment: What version of the jar do you have? Does the jar file contain a file named `META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver`? What version of Java are you using?

Comment: Hey, as mentioned above. This exact same jar worked on a different tomcat. I don't think the jar is missing anything. I'm using ibm java 1.8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After spending some time trying to figure this one out I find out the problem. My drivers were not being registered by DriverManager. The quick fix I found for this was to manually register it before trying to load the driver.

```
DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver());
```

This has solved my issue. The way I found out about this was to print out all the registered drivers and print them out. Not the most elegant solution but it helped me find out what I'm missing.

```
        /*
        System.out.println("checking for drivers");
        Enumeration<Driver> myDrivers = DriverManager.getDrivers();
        System.out.println(myDrivers.hasMoreElements());

        while(myDrivers.hasMoreElements()){
            System.out.println(myDrivers.nextElement().toString());
        }
        */
```

Comment: You deserve one thousand upvotes ! I lost an entire day because my setup was working correctly in Windows, but not on Linux, even when using the exact same version of Java's SDK! I already had discovered that the driver was not being automatically registered and that line saved my day! Appreciated

Comment: @HenriquedeSousa your comment just made my day.

Answer (score 0):

WEB-INF/lib is in your application. It might be so that tomcat needs this driver before your app is loaded? Try putting it into the tomcat's lib folder and restarting...

Here is another question on the same topic: [Why must the JDBC driver be put in TOMCAT_HOME/lib folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6981564/why-must-the-jdbc-driver-be-put-in-tomcat-home-lib-folder)

Comment: No luck :/ I moved it to the lib folder, restarted and redeployed.. Same error.

Comment: Can you give the full path of the lib folder you put it in?

Comment: My path is: /home/florin/Downloads/Tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.6/lib

Comment: Maybe, try this one: Class.forName("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver"); 
It might be that linux jvm doesn't load the class automatically...

Comment: I did try that one. It's throws the class not found error.

Comment: Go ahead and check inside the .jar file (it's just a zip, so unzip it) what is the actual path... Maybe, this is the right one: Class.forName("com.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2Driver");

Comment: Sorry, I'm out of suggestions... maybe, check the logs to see that TOMCAT_HOME (or CATALINA_HOME) points to the right path...