# Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver' in "intellij idea"

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

How to resolve 404 error showing "The requested resource is not available".While running spring mvc hibernate program in intellij idea.There for we are using server configuration as Tomcat 8 with the help of Maven

Error that am getting is.......

```
INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
WARN org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl - HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'
INFO : org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
INFO : org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder - HHH000422: Disabling contextual LOB creation as connection was null
INFO : org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator - HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
INFO : org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory - HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'appServlet': initialization completed in 9709 ms
[2018-11-01 01:10:28,950] Artifact SpringMVCHibernate:war: Artifact is deployed successfully
[2018-11-01 01:10:28,950] Artifact SpringMVCHibernate:war: Deploy took 21,936 milliseconds
WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'
WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'
WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'
```

My xml file configurations are given below

servlet-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

<!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
    infrastructure -->

<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<annotation-driven />

<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
    up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
    in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<beans:bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <beans:property name="url"
        value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/*****" />
    <beans:property name="username" value="*****" />
    <beans:property name="password" value="*****" />
</beans:bean>

<!-- Hibernate 4 SessionFactory Bean definition -->
<beans:bean id="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <beans:property name="annotatedClasses">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.Person</beans:value>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
        <beans:props>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
            </beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
        </beans:props>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="personDAO" class="com.journaldev.spring.dao.PersonDAOImpl">
    <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="personService" class="com.journaldev.spring.service.PersonServiceImpl">
    <beans:property name="personDAO" ref="personDAO"></beans:property>
</beans:bean>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.journaldev.spring" />

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<beans:bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
</beans:bean>
```

root-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

<!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->
    </beans>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<!-- <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener> -->

<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And also am added Dependency in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.31</version>
    </dependency>
```

My controller class are given below

PersonController.java

```
@Controller
public class PersonController
{
private PersonService personService;
@Autowired(required=true)
@Qualifier(value="personService")
public void setPersonService(PersonService ps)
{
    this.personService = ps;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/persons", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String listPersons(Model model)
{
    model.addAttribute("person", new Person());
    model.addAttribute("listPersons", this.personService.listPersons());
    return "person";
}

//For add and update person both
@RequestMapping(value= "/person/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addPerson(@ModelAttribute("person") Person p){

    if(p.getId() == 0)
    {
        //new person, add it
        this.personService.addPerson(p);
    }
    else
    {
        //existing person, call update
        this.personService.updatePerson(p);
    }

    return "redirect:/persons";

}

@RequestMapping("/remove/{id}")
public String removePerson(@PathVariable("id") int id){

    this.personService.removePerson(id);
    return "redirect:/persons";
}

@RequestMapping("/edit/{id}")
public String editPerson(@PathVariable("id") int id, Model model){
    model.addAttribute("person", this.personService.getPersonById(id));
    model.addAttribute("listPersons", this.personService.listPersons());
    return "person";
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must put the mysql-connector jar inside your tomcat's "lib" folder, not in pom.

[Why must the JDBC driver be put in TOMCAT_HOME/lib folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6981564/why-must-the-jdbc-driver-be-put-in-tomcat-home-lib-folder)