# Added mysql jar to lib but still facing class not found exception on local deployment to tomcat working through intelliJ?

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, intellij-idea

Throughout my application I want to add the username and password to database when a user registers and clicks on "sign up" through `servlet2.java` but on local tomcat deployment instead of adding data to database `class not found exception` is thrown, I have already added mysql jar to lib but still no benefit. Here is the downloadable link to [my project](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1CPSzzJwf5zwvvzcsL2zrQi1KSGD_t0Uv). If anybody can please help correcting the issue.

Here is the full stack trace.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1363)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1186)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:315)
    at source.servlet2.database(servlet2.java:23)
    at source.servlet2.doPost(servlet2.java:16)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:200)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
22-May-2019 19:22:52.550 INFO [Catalina-utility-2] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [D:\apache-tomcat-9.0.17\webapps\manager]
22-May-2019 19:22:52.735 INFO [Catalina-utility-2] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [D:\apache-tomcat-9.0.17\webapps\manager] has finished in [185] ms
```

Comment: Can you please add the stack trace as well.

Comment: Also, please check if the jars are present in the lib directory inside the application directory under tomcat/webapps/.

Comment: we need a lot more to help. Full stacktrace, the way you added the driver, maven? Manual in IDE? what is the jar you added etc.

Comment: You can add the to tomcat classpath jar as described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/7198049/2000323

Comment: Well I have added the stack trace , I added the jar through project structure/modules/library/maven and then downloaded the latest version of mysql jar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the `provided` scope for the jdbc driver jar. In this cases it is not copied into the artifact that you deploy to tomcat. You need to specify it as a `compile` scope.
[image]

You can also add the to tomcat classpath jar as described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/7198049/2000323 for all applications. Then you must specify the scope as `provided` so that the same jar would not be deployed twice.

Comment: I have added all the 4 war files to tomcat /lib but and marked the scope as provided and tried by both marking and unmarking the export option but still facing the issue,i have added the stack trace as well