# Reduce war size for frequent redeployments(uploads) to a remote server

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment, jar, war

While development I need to frequently update my web app source code & deploy the updated war to a remote Tomcat server. Uploading a big war(25MB) takes too long(around 30 min) on my connection which is very unproductive. Is there any way I could reduce the war size ? There are a lot of external dependencies in my project. Could I deploy just the changes(may be dependencies remain intact) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are asking (`Could I deploy just the changes?`) cannot be done. There are other things you can do though to reduce the file size of your war file:

1. You can place libraries in tomcat's common directory (tomcat-dir/common/lib) and remove them from your dependencies in your war file ([Does Tomcat load the same library file into memory twice if they are in two web apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267953/managing-libraries-in-tomcat)).
2. Place static file on a cdn or another web application on your tomcat (that would require code modification though)

Answer (score 5):

It depends how much control you have over the upload process. If you have remote access to the filesystem, the following should work:

- Upload the WAR
- Let Tomcat expand it
- Stop Tomcat
- Delete the WAR
- Start Tomcat
- Tomcat should run your app from the expanded directory
- Upload changed files only and replace the old ones in the expanded directory
- For static files, no further action is necessary
- If up update classes or JARs, you'll need to restart Tomcat

Answer (score 1):

You can use git hooks (http://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks). Altough, this requires a git repository on your webserver. Deployments may triggered by push events.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if exploded war deployment is an option for you then you could use [kwatee](http://www.kwatee.net). It's a free and unrestricted tool (I'm the author) with a simple web interface (or CLI automation) that can do incremental exploded war updates and many other things.