# Reduce size of war file of maven application

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven

My web application's war file size is 45Mb.It is spring +hibernart+maven based application.my total code size is 13Mb,then all war size is too much.I want to reduce this size.Please give me solution.

Comment: Your code is is 13Mb so I guess the 3rd party libraries constitute the rest, 32Mb. Simple, reduce you dependencies.

Comment: Check this post might help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18525641/reduce-war-size-for-frequent-redeploymentsuploads-to-a-remote-server

Comment: "then all war size is too much" - why? It isn't unusual for JEE applications to go into the 100mb+ due to all the third party libraries that may be attached.

Answer (score 1):

You may look at the http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/ to find out if you can reduce your dependencies.

If you are ok with removing debugging information, you can also add http://proguard.sourceforge.net/ to your build.