# Shared library folder for deployed tomacat web application

Tags: java, web-applications, tomcat7, shared-libraries, external

I there any way to configure a shared external library location for multiple J2ee based web application which deployed in tomcat.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/267953/does-tomcat-load-the-same-library-file-into-memory-twice-if-they-are-in-two-web

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the shared libraries in Tomcat's `common/lib` folder, and they will be available for all the webapps deployed on that server.

However, please note that deploying multiple applications on a single Tomcat server is considered bad practice. 
Tomcat is very lightweight, so running one instance per application is perfectly acceptable from a performance point of view. Also, it allows you to fine-tune Tomcat's memory, configuration, librairies, etc. differently for each web application.

Comment: Thank for solution