# Servlet error when changing JAR from compile to provided

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, wsdl, spring-ws

I am currently trying to move a JAR from a deployed WAR to just being included in the Tomcat library. Here's the dependency in my `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>psft.pt8</groupId>
    <artifactId>psjoa</artifactId>
    <version>8.54.22</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

When scope is `<scope>compile</scope>` everything works fine. I build the artifact, deploy it in Tomcat, and can access the WSDL. When I change scope to provided, I can still build the artifact, deploy it in Tomcat, it LOOKS like it's fine, but then when attempting to go to the WSDL I reach this error.

```
The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request: Servlet.init() for servlet spring-ws threw exception
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet spring-ws threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    psiprobe.Tomcat80AgentValve.invoke(Tomcat80AgentValve.java:45)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:676)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:670)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Not sure where to begin.

Comment: did you put the jar in tomcat lib folder

Comment: Yes I did. I have another project where I've moved the same jar to the lib folder and it works fine. I've tried this current one with both that jar, and the jar that it creates when it is set to compile.

Comment: take a look at this S.O discussion may help you to configure you tomcat :     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/267953/does-tomcat-load-the-same-library-file-into-memory-twice-if-they-are-in-two-web

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1.**

If you don't want including artifact `psft.pt8:psjoa:8.54.22` inside WAR generated artifact

- use `<scope>provided</scope>` in `pom.xml`
- put `psft.pt8:psjoa:8.54.22` JAR file inside `$CATALINA_HOME\lib` (on macOS, Linux) or `%CATALINA_HOME%\lib` (on Windows operating system).

**Solution 2.**

If you want including artifact `psft.pt8:psjoa:8.54.22` inside WAR generated artifact, use `<scope>compile</scope>` in `pom.xml`.